# How to install GEMMA2 (gemma2lib) on GNU Guix over Ubuntu 22.04 running via WSL2?

Tags: package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux, guix

I'm running Windows subsystem for Linux 2 (Ubuntu 22.04).
I'd like to run [GEMMA2 (gemma2lib)](https://github.com/genetics-statistics/gemma2lib): in the [link](https://github.com/genetics-statistics/gemma2lib/blob/master/INSTALL.org) it is said:

```
~/opt/guix/bin/guix package -i python python-toolz -p ~/opt/gemmalib  
. ~/opt/gemmalib/etc/profile
```

from the code I understood that I have to install GNU Guix first. I did it with:

```
sudo apt install guix
```

but the `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\opt` directory is empty.
`\\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\var` directory does not contain `daemon-socket`.
Meanwhile `guix` is in `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\usr\bin` directory and when I run `guix help` I can see help.
When I run
`guix package -i python python-toolz -p ~/opt/gemmalib`
here is an error:
`` guix package: error: failed to connect to `/var/guix/daemon-socket/socket': No such file or directory ``

What should I do next...?

Maybe I have to install GNU Guix with the [script](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guix.git/plain/etc/guix-install.sh) as decribed [here](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Installation.html)?
Or maybe there is a problem with [`-p profile`](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Invoking-guix-package.html)?

Please help to newbie...

**UPDATE:**
`sudo service guix-daemon service`
returns: Usage: /etc/init.d/guix-daemon (start|stop|status|restart|force-reload)

`/etc/init.d/guix-daemon status`
returns: guix-daemon is not running

`/etc/init.d/guix-daemon start`
returns: /etc/init.d/guix-daemon: line 35: daemonize: command not found

`guix package -i python python-toolz`
guix package: error: failed to connect to `/var/guix/daemon-socket/socket': Connection refused

I can see that `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\var\guix\daemon-socket\socket` file is of 0 Kb.

Comment: Sounds like you need to start guix as a daemon. Have you looked at the documentation? Should be explained in there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have only github gemma2lib link as a documentation. Or this is meant https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Invoking-guix_002ddaemon.html ?

Comment: Yes, I meant the guix documentation. The error says it couldn't find a running daemon, so I am guessing you need to launch a daemon, so that should be the relevant section, yes. Sorry, I hadn't even heard of guix before this question so I can't give you any specific details.